# Can I tap a creature with summoning sickness to pay "tap an untapped creature you control" costs?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Chosen of Markov](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243229) on the battlefield and I played a vampire earlier this turn. Can I tap both to transform Chosen of Markov even though I just played the vampire?

**Extra Example:** I play [Battle Screech](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=35079) to put two 1/1 white bird tokens into play. Can I now tap a both of them and another creature I control to pay Battle Screech's flashback cost of tapping three white creatures?

Obviously these creatures couldn't use any tap abilities until my next turn, but since the tapping is coming from a different source, I figured the situation might be different.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can. Relevant rule:

> 302.6. A creature’s activated ability **with the tap symbol or the untap symbol** in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. A creature can’t attack unless it has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. This rule is informally called the “summoning sickness” rule.

This is the tap symbol:

[image: tap symbol]

The only limit that summoning sickness imposes is about the tap symbol . "Tap an untapped Vampire you control" is not the tap symbol.

It has nothing to do with being from another source. [Heritage Druid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHeritage%20Druid%5d) could tap herself the turn she comes out.

Comment: Added a little for completeness.

Comment: bear in mind that some older cards might not use the tap symbol or they might use a different tap symbol

Comment: @Sam I am, What's printed on the card is of no importance. It's what's in Gatherer that matters, and Gatherer only uses the new symbol, even for old cards.